# Conditional/ternary result not type checked correctly in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

```
type User = {
    name: string;
};
const flag: any = false;
let list1: User;
list1 = flag ? flag : 1;   // hope error
```

Why list1 can be 1, why not an error: Type '1' is not assignable to type 'User'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `any` in the annotation to `flag`. `any` is by definition assignable to any type and assignable from any type. This means that the result of the expression `flag ? flag : 1` will be `any` (since one of the results of the ternary expression is `any` the type of the expression is `any | 1` which will get reduced to `any`).

Generally avoid `any`. If you really don't know a type at compile time use `unknown`. In this case removing the annotation yields an error as expected:

```
type User = {
    name: string;
};
const flag = false; // no annotation 
let list1: User;
list1 = flag ? flag : 1; // err
```

Comment: also a general remark, it is better to use `interface` instead of `type/class` if you don't implement any methods on the interface u create (like domain objects with only the property definitions, or POJO in Java). It makes your `class/type` more lightweight

Comment: @RobRombouts `type` and `interface` basically the same thing in this case. `class` is a different beast. But `type` and `interface` are both types that are erased at compile time (they differ in what can be done with them in the type system but for this simple example there is no practical difference)

Comment: thanks for clearing that up for me, the advantage of an interface over a type is that an interface can be extended, type cant, got confused with that. I always use interface for that reason.

Comment: @RobRombouts types can be used as a base type for an interface. They can't extend other interfaces themselves (although intersections model this well enough). Types can't participate in merging so that extension avenue is closed. Either one will work fro simple cases, although I usually prefer interfaces too :)